# Nodejs require module from external folder

Tags: node.js

I'm developing microservice architecture on nodejs. 
I moved 'core' functionality to separate git repository, and each 'service' add that core as npm dependency.

In service I use core as

```
require('core/module1');
```

In that case nodejs takes 'core' from node_modules, it's ok for production but for development I want to take 'core' from the external folder not from node_modules.

My main idea - do changes in 'core' and immidiately get the result in 'service'.

I cannot use NODE_PATH for specify external 'core' folder, because I've used it now.

I found solution to use 'app-module-path' module for adding additional directories to the Node.js module search path.

```
if(isDevelopment()){
    require('app-module-path').addPath('path_to_core_folder');
}
```

It's working solution, but maybe you can suggest some more clear way?

My folders structure

```
- core
    module1

- service1
    -index.js
    -node_modules
      -core
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either one works. If you require('modulename') and it's present in your node_modules folder, it will be loaded from there. If you want it to load from another folder or from your main folder, you need to do require('./modulename") which will look for it in the current folder. Alternatively you can do require('./my_modules/modulename') which will work for a subfolder.

Comment: Node will not look for the module in your main folder. To do that you need to explicitly tell node to look for the module in your main folder. To do that you do `require('./mymodule')` instead of `require('mymodule')`. The second version will ALWAYS look for the module in `node_modules`. Same goes for your second example. It MUST be `require('./my_modules/modulename')`

Comment: @Neekoy I got it. But in my case, for development, I want nodejs resolve core from the folder that doesn't present in main 'service' folder.

Comment: Slebetman is actually correct and it needs the dot that I missed in the answer. I edited my response to the correct info.

Comment: What if I have a configuration file in the parent directory which is not a NPM package, is just a JSON call that depends on the environment variables to be included? I'm ŧrying require('../config/config') and config is a switch which requires a JSON file depending on the NODE_ENV variable. I got an error: validating package
Error: Cannot find module '../config/config'

Answer (score 0):

i would look at the mockrequire module, it allows you to redirect the directory your modules are loaded from

Answer (score 0):

**npm link** is the answer to your problem. You can run the below command in the root directory of 'service1' (where your package.json is present)

```
npm link [../relative-path-to/library]
```

Refer to https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-link for more details about npm link.